# I was trying to run sql code in azure data studio but i got an operating system error 5(Access is denied) MSG 5123 Level 16

Tags: linux, azure-sql-database

Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file '/home/Desktop/Vjezba_DB'.

While I was trying to create a database I got this error tried to find an answer online but no luck. Also I'm using ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a permissions error. The account which is running the SQL Server doesn't have the needed rights on the folder which will contain the database files.

You need to give the account which is running SQL Server (not your account) full control of C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA.

Instead of giving permissions to Everyone you should grant read and write permissions to SQL Server Service account.

here are steps to find SQL Server service account

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/24/how-to-find-service-account-for-sql-server-and-sql-server-agent-interview-question-of-the-week-179/

If you wanted to change the default file locations you can do that here are examples:

https://sqlandme.com/2013/03/18/sql-server-changing-default-database-location-for-server/

Comment: No need to use @OP, the original poster always gets notified of answers automatically.